# A Bundle_Key displayes wrong value after it is passed to another Activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, bundle

I have an activity "AddLoc" which saves the path of the image taken into a bundle "Bundle_1". I check whether the bundle "Bundle_1" contains the full path of the image taken or not by a `toast` that displays the value contained in the path_key, and it displays the full path. Also, in the `onActivityResult()` I checked again the value of the `imgPath` and it displays the full path.To note, the variable `imgPath` that should contains the full path of the image taken is of type `File` and I am generating the path as shown in the code.  up-to here there is no problem and every thing is duly.

the problem starts when the bundle "Bundle_1" is passed to another activity "LocFix", which unpacks the bundle passed to it "Bundle_1" and saves its values into `Sqlite` DataBase.

Before I save the values contained in the "Bundle_1" into the DataBase, I checked the value of the path_key using `toast`, and I expect that the toast will display again the full path of the image taken, but, it just displays the title of the image "imgtitle.jpeg" and NOT the full path of it as it supposes to display. Why the full path of the image is not being displayed?

Java_Code" in this code the value of the img_path is correct and is displayed in full:

```
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(isDeviceHasCamera() == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   
     DEVICE_HAS_NO_CAMERA, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if(isDeviceHasFrontFacingCamera() == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
     DEVICE_HAS_NO_FRONT_FACING_CAMERA, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            imgTitle = generateImgTitle();
            imgPath = generateImgPath(imgTitle);
            Log.d(TAG,"@alertdialogPositiveButton(): imageTitle="+imgTitle+", imgPath="+imgPath);

            mPositiveBtnIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            mPositiveBtnIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri(imgPath));
            startActivityForResult(mPositiveBtnIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_CODE);
        }   
    }

private Uri getImageUri(File imgPath) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Uri imgFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imgPath);
        Log.d(TAG,"@getImageUri(): imgPath="+imgPath);
        Log.d(TAG,"@getImageUri(): imgFileUri="+imgFileUri.toString());
        return imgFileUri;
    }

    private File generateImgPath(String ImgTitle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(dir,"/DCIM/MPL/"+ImgTitle); 
        Log.d(TAG,"@generateImgPath(): imgPath as File="+file.getPath());
        Log.d(TAG,"@generateImgPath(): img Absolute path="+file.getAbsolutePath());
        return file;
    }

    private String generateImgTitle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mEditText.getText().toString() + ".jpeg";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Iam a bit confused, but, I recommend to save the path of the image as `string`. Which means the `bundle` should contain a `string` representation of the path and not `URI` or `FILE`. try to save in the bundle `YOUR_FILE.toString()`.